# How to change a ComboBox to display items in a Loader?

Tags: qml, qt-quick

I would like to have a ComboBox that handles large amounts of content by loading them asynchronously inside a Loader, so I can display a little BusyIndicator over the drop-down.
Is it maybe possible to achieve this through a style? I want to avoid having to recreate a ComboBox from scratch.

Answer (score 3):

No. It [may be possible in the future](https://bugreports.qt.io/browse/QTBUG-39476?focusedCommentId=246471&page=com.atlassian.jira.plugin.system.issuetabpanels:comment-tabpanel#comment-246471), though:

> This one is a bit tricky to get right, and is still work in progress. It is not difficult to style the popup background, the same way it's currently doable for MenuStyle. What remains, as you pointed out, is to make that API public.
>
> What we can't promise, is to be able to style the popup window shape. If QtQuick was backing store based, then most platforms support shaping the window. But QtQuick is OpenGL based, and desktop platforms support this in different ways. On mobile and embedded platforms, we can't use a separate window, so we need to build an abstraction that would use Item-based popups.

I'd suggest voting for and watching [QTBUG-39476](https://bugreports.qt.io/browse/QTBUG-39476) if you're interested in this feature and don't want to write your own `ComboBox`.

Comment: Alright, thanks. I'll look into alternatives for now.